# Do I need e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, preventdefault, stoppropagation

In JavaScript/jQuery, I am registering click and touchstart events on a button, with this:

```
$('#open-about-popup').on('touchstart click', openAboutPopup_eventHandler)
```

Then in the event-handler, I have this:

```
e.stopPropagation(); 
e.preventDefault();
```

This is causing the next button-click not to fire. Do I have something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you read the documentation to find out what those functions do?

Comment: The codes `e.stopPropagation(); 
e.preventDefault();` will stop the default action.

Comment: Do you want to have next button click to be triggered then remove those 2 lines.

Comment: I think I need them, because I have touchstart and click, together. Maybe I need just one of them.And I did read the documentation

Answer (score 2):

`e.stopPropagation()` prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree, `e.preventDefault()` prevents the browser from doing whatever default behavior is associated with the event - e.g. a click event on an `<a>` tag will make the browser redirect to the `href` of the link, but if you use `preventDefault`, it won't do that.

Answer (score -1):

I fund the problem. It is unrelated to the post. Thanks.